# Type error in Standard ML reverse function

Tags: sml

I am extremely new to sml.  I cannot see what is wrong for this simple reverse function I am trying to write.

```
fun reverse [] = [] | 
    reverse (v1::rest) = (reverse(tl(rest)) @ v1)
```

This is the output when I try to run reverse([1, 2, 3]);

```
poly: : error: Type error in function application.
Function: reverse : 'a list list -> 'a list
Argument: ([1, 2, 3]) : int list
Reason:
  Can't unify int (*In Basis*) with 'a list (*In Basis*)
     (Different type constructors)
Found near reverse ([1, 2, 3])
Static Errors
```

I can see that it is a type error.  It appears that reverse is looking for 2 lists (I think..'a list list seems like a weird type to me)??  Is there a problem with how I have the pattern/parameters setup?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see now that instead of @ I should have ::, but I still get a similar error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's address the wrong type issue first.

`'a list list` means a list of lists, like this one:

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] : int list list
```

which is a list of lists of integers.

The overall type of your `reverse` function is

```
val reverse = fn : 'a list list -> 'a list
```

This happens because the `@` operator has the following type signature (you can find the docs [here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html)).

```
val @ : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list
```

So, the type inference mechanism infers that `v1` is an `'a list`, but that means the input list contains elements of type `'a list` and hence should be of type `'a list list`.

But what you really meant is to append the element `v1` to the end of the reversed tail, and this can be easily achieved by making `v1` into a list of one element:

`some_list @ [v1]`

Next, you don't need `tl(rest)`, since `rest` is already the tail of your input list. As a side note: it's more idiomatic to write `tl rest`, the parentheses are unessential here.

Taking the above into account we get the following implementation:

```
fun rev [] = []
  | rev (h::tl) = rev tl @ [h]
```

I should warn you that this function is very inefficient, since it's time complexity is quadratic (O(n^2)).

Comment: I notice the above function produces a result that does not include the last element for some reason.   My next question would be how come it also does not work when I simply change the @ to :: and remove the tl() function?

Comment: Whoops my mistake, I was still calling reverse!  Sorry about that and thank you for the help!  I also realize now that :: is no where near the right since it is simply a pattern (I am very sleep deprived).  Again sorry about that!

Comment: You can't append an element at the end of a list like that. `::` has type `'a * 'a list -> 'a list`, so the type inferencer would again infer `'a list` for `v1` in that case (note that `reverse` won't type check at all if you swap `@` and `::`). Lists are asymmetrical: you can easily prepend elements with `::` but appending is much harder. HTH